# can't install node module in exiting project based on React.js with native

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules, uglifyjs, npm-package

Getting error when I run npm install I want run the exiting react project with react native both project combine in one.

i have install nvm for change node version with npm
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUm7A.png)
[node verison and npm version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na0nf.png)

```
npm WARN deprecated @types/pusher-js@5.1.0: This is a stub types definition. pusher-js provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm WARN deprecated @types/concurrently@7.0.0: This is a stub types definition. concurrently provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm WARN deprecated dommatrix@1.0.3: dommatrix is no longer maintained. Please use @thednp/dommatrix.
npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\Brijesh\react js\HG\Expensify\App\node_modules\shellcheck
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c ./install.sh
npm ERR! '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\brije\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-11T06_29_30_567Z-debug-0.log
```

package json like below

```
{
  "name": "new.expensify",
  "version": "1.3.66-3",
  "author": "Expensify, Inc.",
  "homepage": "https://new.expensify.com",
  "description": "New Expensify is the next generation of Expensify: a reimagination of payments based atop a foundation of chat.",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "configure-mapbox": "scripts/setup-mapbox-sdk-walkthrough.sh",
    "postinstall": "scripts/postInstall.sh",
    "clean": "npx react-native clean-project-auto",
    "android": "scripts/set-pusher-suffix.sh && npx react-native run-android --variant=developmentDebug --appId=com.expensify.chat.dev",
    "ios": "scripts/set-pusher-suffix.sh && npx react-native run-ios --configuration=\"Debug Development\" --scheme=\"New Expensify Dev\"",
    "pod-install": "cd ios && bundle exec pod install",
    "ipad": "concurrently \"npx react-native run-ios --simulator=\\\"iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (6th generation)\\\" --configuration=\\\"Debug Development\\\" --scheme=\\\"New Expensify Dev\\\"\"",
    "ipad-sm": "concurrently \"npx react-native run-ios --simulator=\\\"iPad Pro (11-inch) (4th generation)\\\" --configuration=\\\"Debug Development\\\" --scheme=\\\"New Expensify Dev\\\"\"",
    "start": "npx react-native start",
    "web": "scripts/set-pusher-suffix.sh && concurrently npm:web-proxy npm:web-server",
    "web-proxy": "node web/proxy.js",
    "web-server": "webpack-dev-server --open --config config/webpack/webpack.dev.js",
    "build": "webpack --config config/webpack/webpack.common.js --env envFile=.env.production",
    "build-staging": "webpack --config config/webpack/webpack.common.js --env envFile=.env.staging",
    "build-adhoc": "webpack --config config/webpack/webpack.common.js --env envFile=.env.adhoc",
    "desktop": "scripts/set-pusher-suffix.sh && node desktop/start.js",
    "desktop-build": "scripts/build-desktop.sh production",
    "desktop-build-staging": "scripts/build-desktop.sh staging",
    "createDocsRoutes": "node .github/scripts/createDocsRoutes.js",
    "desktop-build-adhoc": "scripts/build-desktop.sh adhoc",
    "ios-build": "fastlane ios build",
    "android-build": "fastlane android build",
    "android-build-e2e": "bundle exec fastlane android build_e2e",
    "test": "TZ=utc jest",
    "typecheck": "tsc",
    "lint": "eslint . --max-warnings=0 --cache --cache-location=node_modules/.cache/eslint",
    "lint-changed": "eslint --fix $(git diff --diff-filter=AM --name-only main -- \"*.js\" \"*.ts\" \"*.tsx\")",
    "lint-watch": "npx eslint-watch --watch --changed",
    "shellcheck": "./scripts/shellCheck.sh",
    "prettier": "prettier --write .",
    "prettier-watch": "onchange \"**/*.{js,ts,tsx}\" -- prettier --write --ignore-unknown {{changed}}",
    "print-version": "echo $npm_package_version",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "storybook-build": "ENV=production build-storybook -o dist/docs",
    "storybook-build-staging": "ENV=staging build-storybook -o dist/docs",
    "gh-actions-build": "./.github/scripts/buildActions.sh",
    "gh-actions-validate": "./.github/scripts/validateActionsAndWorkflows.sh",
    "analyze-packages": "ANALYZE_BUNDLE=true webpack --config config/webpack/webpack.common.js --env envFile=.env.production",
    "symbolicate:android": "npx metro-symbolicate android/app/build/generated/sourcemaps/react/release/index.android.bundle.map",
    "symbolicate:ios": "npx metro-symbolicate main.jsbundle.map",
    "test:e2e": "node tests/e2e/testRunner.js --development"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expensify/react-native-web": "0.18.15",
    "@formatjs/intl-getcanonicallocales": "^2.2.0",
    "@formatjs/intl-listformat": "^7.2.2",
    "@formatjs/intl-locale": "^3.3.0",
    "@formatjs/intl-numberformat": "^8.5.0",
    "@formatjs/intl-pluralrules": "^5.2.2",
    "@gorhom/portal": "^1.0.14",
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.2.2",
    "@oguzhnatly/react-native-image-manipulator": "github:Expensify/react-native-image-manipulator#5cdae3d4455b03a04c57f50be3863e2fe6c92c52",
    "@onfido/react-native-sdk": "7.4.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
    "@react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll": "5.4.0",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.5.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.10",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^12.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^12.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/perf": "^12.3.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^10.0.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.3",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "6.3.16",
    "@react-ng/bounds-observer": "^0.2.1",
    "@rnmapbox/maps": "^10.0.11",
    "@ua/react-native-airship": "^15.2.6",
    "awesome-phonenumber": "^5.4.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "canvas-size": "^1.2.6",
    "core-js": "^3.32.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "date-fns-tz": "^2.0.0",
    "dom-serializer": "^0.2.2",
    "domhandler": "^4.3.0",
    "expensify-common": "git+ssh://git@github.com/Expensify/expensify-common.git#e63d06e239fe5b2f221e86eab71ae8a4e3b8bee3",
    "fbjs": "^3.0.2",
    "htmlparser2": "^7.2.0",
    "idb-keyval": "^6.2.1",
    "jest-when": "^3.5.2",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "lottie-react-native": "^5.1.6",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.15.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "onfido-sdk-ui": "13.1.0",
    "patch-package": "^8.0.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "pusher-js": "7.4.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-collapse": "^5.1.0",
    "react-content-loader": "^6.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-map-gl": "^7.1.3",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-blob-util": "^0.17.3",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-config": "^1.4.5",
    "react-native-dev-menu": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.3.0",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^8.0.0",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.12.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "git+https://github.com/Expensify/react-native-google-places-autocomplete.git#ee87343c3e827ff7818abc71b6bb04fcc1f120e0",
    "react-native-haptic-feedback": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.12",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-image-size": "git+https://github.com/Expensify/react-native-image-size#8393b7e58df6ff65fd41f60aee8ece8822c91e2b",
    "react-native-key-command": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.1",
    "react-native-localize": "^2.2.6",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-onyx": "1.0.72",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-pdf": "^6.7.1",
    "react-native-performance": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-picker-select": "git+https://github.com/Expensify/react-native-picker-select.git#eae05855286dc699954415cc1d629bfd8e8e47e2",
    "react-native-plaid-link-sdk": "^10.0.0",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-quick-sqlite": "^8.0.0-beta.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "3.4.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "6.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.21.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.9.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-view-shot": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "^2.15.4",
    "react-native-web-linear-gradient": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-web-lottie": "^1.4.4",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.17.2",
    "react-pdf": "^6.2.2",
    "react-plaid-link": "3.3.2",
    "react-web-config": "^1.0.0",
    "react-window": "^1.8.9",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "semver": "^7.5.2",
    "shim-keyboard-event-key": "^1.0.3",
    "underscore": "^1.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@actions/core": "1.10.0",
    "@actions/github": "5.1.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.12.13",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.21.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@electron/notarize": "^1.2.3",
    "@jest/globals": "^29.5.0",
    "@octokit/core": "4.0.4",
    "@octokit/plugin-paginate-rest": "3.1.0",
    "@octokit/plugin-throttling": "4.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "3.0.0",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.9",
    "@react-navigation/devtools": "^6.0.10",
    "@storybook/addon-a11y": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.0.0",
    "@storybook/addon-react-native-web": "0.0.19--canary.37.cb55428.0",
    "@storybook/addons": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/theming": "^6.5.9",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^6.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "5.4.1",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "11.5.1",
    "@types/concurrently": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/jest-when": "^3.5.2",
    "@types/js-yaml": "^4.0.5",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.195",
    "@types/mapbox-gl": "^2.7.13",
    "@types/mock-fs": "^4.13.1",
    "@types/pusher-js": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.12",
    "@types/react-collapse": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.4",
    "@types/react-pdf": "^5.7.2",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/semver": "^7.5.0",
    "@types/setimmediate": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.11.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.2.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.2.1",
    "@vercel/ncc": "^0.27.0",
    "@welldone-software/why-did-you-render": "7.0.1",
    "ajv-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "29.4.1",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-native-web": "^0.18.7",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.4.1",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.2",
    "diff-so-fancy": "^1.3.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "electron": "^25.4.0",
    "electron-builder": "24.5.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-expensify": "^2.0.38",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^46.2.6",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native-a11y": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.5.13",
    "eslint-plugin-you-dont-need-lodash-underscore": "^6.12.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "jest": "29.4.1",
    "jest-circus": "29.4.1",
    "jest-cli": "29.4.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.4.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.7",
    "mock-fs": "^4.13.0",
    "onchange": "^7.1.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.28",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "pusher-js-mock": "^0.3.3",
    "react-native-clean-project": "^4.0.0-alpha4.0",
    "react-native-flipper": "https://gitpkg.now.sh/facebook/flipper/react-native/react-native-flipper?9cacc9b59402550eae866e0e81e5f0c2f8203e6b",
    "react-native-performance-flipper-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "reassure": "^0.9.0",
    "setimmediate": "^1.0.5",
    "shellcheck": "^1.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "time-analytics-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.17",
    "type-fest": "^3.12.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "wait-port": "^0.2.9",
    "webpack": "^5.76.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.3",
    "webpack-font-preload-plugin": "^1.5.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "react-native": "$react-native"
  },
  "electronmon": {
    "patterns": [
      "!node_modules",
      "!node_modules/**/*",
      "!**/*.map",
      "!ios/**",
      "!android/**",
      "*.test.*",
      "*.spec.*"
    ]
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.15.1",
    "npm": "8.11.0"
  }
}
```

I have also try with clean npm cache and remove package-lock and then npm install but still not working.

if you have any idea please let me know.

I have try using Mac PC, with brew with nvm this is working fine but in my window laptop this is not working because brew is not supported in window so I go through direct nvm for node version change.

I'm expecting install node module in exiting project in Window this is working in fine in Mac PC.

Thanks you.

Comment: Which package manager are you using?

Comment: npm package manager

Comment: Try to use yarn for this

Answer (score -1):

Here are some additional steps you can try to troubleshoot and resolve the problem:

1. **Upgrade npm:** Your project specifies npm version 8.11.0, which is a relatively old version. Try upgrading npm to a more recent version, as older versions may have compatibility issues:

   npm install -g npm@latest

After upgrading npm, try running npm install again.

2. **Run as Administrator:** In some cases, permissions issues can prevent npm from working correctly on Windows. Try running your terminal or command prompt as an administrator and then running npm install.
3. **Antivirus/Security Software:** Some antivirus or security software on your Windows machine might interfere with the installation process. Try temporarily disabling such software while running npm install to see if it resolves the issue.
4. **Use Yarn:** Consider using Yarn as an alternative package manager to npm. Yarn is known to be more reliable in certain situations. You can install Yarn globally and then use it to install dependencies:

   npm install -g yarn
   yarn install
5. **Install Windows-Build-Tools:** If your project has dependencies with native code that require compilation (e.g., node-gyp), you may need to install the windows-build-tools package globally to ensure that compilation tools are available:

   npm install -g windows-build-tools

Comment: npm install -g windows-build-tools

this package is deprecated any alternative solution 
simply i want run the run code 

clone and try into window pc and let me know if start this project without any issues
https://github.com/Expensify/App